# Code is Outputting Incorrectly

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, python-3.x

The code shown below is outputting everything on my CSV sheet. It's not suppose to do that. Instead, the goal is to match `Year` and `data_location`, which finally prints the information in that row.

```
 Example if I input:
 Year=1
 data_location=1
```

-

```
Desired OUTPUT should be: Bus #:126688 Area Station:B New Load:125
                          Bus #:126695 Area Station:m New Load:85
                          Bus #:126696 Area Station:O New Load:77
```

-

```
import csv

LOAD_GEN_DATAFILE = 'C:\Users\RoszkowskiM\Desktop\Data_2017.csv' # CSV File to Read


# read the entire CSV into Python.
# CSV has columns starting with Year,busnum,busname,scaled_power,tla,location

# read the entire CSV into Python.
# CSV has columns starting with Year,busnum,busname,scaled_power,tla,location



year = raw_input("Please Select Year of Study: ")

location=raw_input(" \n The list above show the TLA Pockets as well as the ID numbers assigned to them ()\n\n Please enter the ID #: ")

Year=year
data_location=location


data = list(csv.reader(open(LOAD_GEN_DATAFILE)))
mydict = {}

for row in data:
    Year,busnum,busname,scaled_power,tla,data_location,empty,year_link,from_,to,digit,name2,tla_2,min_value,max_value,last_bus = row[0:16]


    #If this is a year not seen before, add it to the dictionary
    if Year not in mydict:
        mydict[Year] = {}

    busses_in_year = mydict[Year]
    if data_location not in busses_in_year:
         busses_in_year[data_location] = []


    #Add the bus to the list of busses that stop at this location
    busses_in_year[data_location].append((busnum,busname,scaled_power))

    if Year in mydict and data_location in mydict[Year]:  
        busses_in_year = mydict[Year]

    #print("Here are all the busses at that location for that year and the new LOAD TOTAL: ")
    #print("\n")

    #Busnum, busname,scaled_power read from excel sheet matching year and location

        for busnum,busname,scaled_power in busses_in_year[data_location]:
            scaled_power= float(scaled_power)
            busnum = int(busnum)

            output='Bus #: {}\t Area Station: {}\t New Load Total: {} MW\t'
            print(output.format(busnum,busname,scaled_power))



    else:
        exit

os.remove(LOAD_GEN_DATAFILE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last `if` statement will always return true because you're checking for `Year` instead of `year`.  As far as I can tell what you're trying to do, you're also going to want to move that statement up one level so it executes after all your rows are added.

```
for row in data:
    Year,busnum,busname,scaled_power,tla,data_location,empty,year_link,from_,to,digit,name2,tla_2,min_value,max_value,last_bus = row[0:16]


    #If this is a year not seen before, add it to the dictionary
    if Year not in mydict:
        mydict[Year] = {}

    busses_in_year = mydict[Year]
    if data_location not in busses_in_year:
         busses_in_year[data_location] = []


    #Add the bus to the list of busses that stop at this location
    busses_in_year[data_location].append((busnum,busname,scaled_power))

if year in mydict and data_location in mydict[year]:  
    busses_in_year = mydict[year]

#print("Here are all the busses at that location for that year and the new LOAD TOTAL: ")
#print("\n")

#Busnum, busname,scaled_power read from excel sheet matching year and location

    for busnum,busname,scaled_power in busses_in_year[data_location]:
        scaled_power= float(scaled_power)
        busnum = int(busnum)

        output='Bus #: {}\t Area Station: {}\t New Load Total: {} MW\t'
        print(output.format(busnum,busname,scaled_power))



else:
    exit

os.remove(LOAD_GEN_DATAFILE)
```

Also, looking into [`dict`'s `setdefault` method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_setdefault.htm) would drastically simplify your `for` loop. You could do something like this:

```
for row in data:
    Year,busnum,busname,scaled_power,tla,data_location,empty,year_link,from_,to,digit,name2,tla_2,min_value,max_value,last_bus = row[0:16]

    value = (busnum, busname, scaled_power)
    mydict.setdefault(Year, {}).setdefault(data_location, []).append(value)
```

Comment: I am not familiar with `set default`. Can you give an example of how I can apply that into my code.

Comment: Actually, nothing is outputting now

Comment: And your `year` and `data_location` are correct? You might output/debugger `mydict` to make sure it's getting constructed properly.